# Melhorando eficiência do Camshift

Tags: python, opencv

Realizo a detecção de um objeto previamente treinado com o algoritmo Haarcascade e passo para o CamShift as coordenadas no inicio do programa para que faça a detecção da região onde o objeto em questão se encontra no primeiro frame. O problema é que apesar de funcionar a precisão está muito ruim. Gostaria de saber técnicas que possam suavizar e melhorar a precisão.

credito que não seja a parte do treinamento pelo fato de encontrar a região facilmente, no caso faces.

## CamShift recebe as coordenadas do objeto detectado

```
for (x, y, l, a) in deteccoes:
width = l
height = a
roi = imagem[y: y+l, x: x+l]

hsv_roi = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
roi_hist = cv2.calcHist([hsv_roi], [0], None, [180], [0, 180])

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
term_criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 100, 10)
while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.calcBackProject([hsv], [0], roi_hist, [0, 180], 1)
    ret, track_window = cv2.CamShift(mask, (x, y, width, height), term_criteria)
    pts = cv2.boxPoints(ret)
    pts = np.int0(pts)
    cv2.polylines(frame, [pts], True, (255, 0, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```